# "npm i" does not respect the package-lock.json file, fetches bad version and changes file

Tags: npm, npm-install

The package-lock.json file has the particular version of a package, however after running "npm i" a later version is installed, and the package-lock.json file has been updated to reflect the later version.

1. Why is this happening? I thought the package-lock.json file was the absolute source of truth.
2. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant

```
npm ci
```

The `npm i` is a short form for `npm install` which uses the `package.json` file.

*ci stands for continuous integration and should never update automatically but use the package-lock.json, which itself will be generated.*